# Language to generate files from template

Tags: code-generation

I want to generates c files from a template that contains some variables. Their initialization is depending on the user.

Do you know any language that generates files from template (e.g adding some tags in the template then generate a c file)?

Note: I'm familiar only with C and python.

Answer (score 2):

Why don’t use a lightweight code generator like **Telosys** ( http://www.telosys.org/ ) ?

With this tool you can define your ‘C’ files templates in Velocity (.vm) files.

Then you can define your variables in the project configuration and just run the code generation.

You can use it in CLI mode :

- http://www.telosys.org/cli.html
- https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-cli/wiki

Or if you already use Eclipse there’s also a plugin : http://www.telosys.org/eclipsePlugin.html